# What does it mean if when someone says. “I don’t know when you will get your chance.”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, questions

I would greatly appreciate it, if someone could please explain this to me.

Comment: Welcome.  You need to provide us with more details before we can answer.  Most importantly, what about this phrase is confusing to you?  It will also help us if you can share something of the context.  What was being discussed when this phrase was spoken?

Answer (score 1):

*I don’t know* [*when you will get your chance*].

The bracketed element is a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), where the meaning is:

*"I don't know the answer to the question 'When will you get your chance?'"*

Answer (score 0):

The person is expressing that he doubts you will have an opportunity in the future.  In other words, your chances are low.